# Minimum amount of permissions required to access a list?

Tags: 2013, permissions

We have several lists that do not inherit permissions from the site, and whenever we try adding users to a group that has "Read" access to a list, the users always get denied access.

We've tried (seemingly) everything - sending the users a link directly to the list, giving their group contribute permissions to the list, etc.  I did some digging on what permissions settings need to be set by default, and made sure that they were OK - things like the Site Images, Style Library, and Master Page Gallery inherit permissions from the site, etc.

Checking a user's permissions against one of the lists shows that they do, in fact, have "Read" access to it.  They are also in a group that has "Read" access to the site itself.  But they still are not able to access it.  Only when given "Full Control" either directly or when placed in a group with "Full Control" access are they able to reach the site and list.

Am I missing anything?

EDIT: The way I worded the question made it sound like users can get to the site, but not the lists...I should have mentioned that users also can't access the site, period.  Regardless of whether or not they are in a group that has read and/or edit permissions.

Comment: what happens if you email a link to the list to them?  Can they access the list this way?  (I'm thinking if they go via the home page and use the navigation there might be a permissions issue that is blocking them)

Comment: Is inheritance is broken on this particular list?

Comment: @Tally If we email a link directly to the list, they still get denied access.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Correct, inheritance is broken.

Comment: I'd make the list inherit permissions again.  Then test if users can access this list.  Once your verify that they can access it, you can again attempt to break inheritance and customise in the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to check below

- Check how it user accessing list, it is via OOTB list view or custom views. Which master page is being applied to application  page like list view.
- Check if master page is not checkout and has published version
- Check if in master page or js file (referred in master page), do you have any script which is running which is running custom js code in which user does not have access.
- Check via chrome developer network tab, keep preserve log on and see which which request is giving unauthorized error and redirecting user to access denied page.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Users access the list through both methods - OOTB views and custom views.  I checked the master page, it's not checked out and is published.  The point about JS files is interesting, though - if a user doesn't have access to one, wouldn't it just fail to load that file, rather than redirect them to the "Access Denied" page?

Comment: You were right - I guess the master page wasn't a major version, so I published it and it all seems to be working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the inheritance is broken on this particular list.

If Yes, then follow below steps:

1. Go to List settings.
2. Select Permissions for this list.
3. Select Check Permissions.
4. Enter User who is not able to access the list and check his/her permissions on the list.
5. To Grant the permissions on list, Select Grant permissions and add User/Group and the permissions from here.